# How to limit the connections count of an HTTP Server implemented in Go?

Tags: go, httpserver

I am trying to implement an HTTP Server in Golang.

My problem is, I have to limit the maximum active connections count at any particular time to 20.

Comment: Using nginx as a reverse proxy is easiest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776584/webserver-for-go-golang-webservices-using-nginx-or-not

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`netutil.LimitListener`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/netutil#LimitListener) function to wrap around `net.Listener` if you don't want to implement your own wrapper:-

```
connectionCount := 20

l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8000")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Listen: %v", err)
}

defer l.Close()

l = netutil.LimitListener(l, connectionCount)

log.Fatal(http.Serve(l, nil))
```

Comment: Does this eliminate the normal `tcpKeepAliveListener` behavior of `http.ListenAndServe`?

Answer (score 5):

The trick with this is to implement your own [net.Listener](http://godoc.org/net#Listener).  I have an example of a listener [here](http://kylelemons.net/browse/gitweb.cgi/go/daemon.git/blob/HEAD:/listen.go) (see waitConn and WaitListener) that tracks connections (but doesn't limit them), which you can use as the inspiration for an implementation.  It will be shaped something like this:

```
type LimitedListener struct {
    sync.Mutex
    net.Listener
    sem chan bool
}

func NewLimitedListener(count int, l net.Listener) *net.LimitedListener {
    sem := make(chan bool, count)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        sem <- true
    }
    return &net.LimitedListener{
        Listener: l,
        sem:      sem,
    }
}

func (l *LimitedListener) Addr() net.Addr { /* ... */ }
func (l *LimitedListener) Close() error { /* ... */ }
func (l *LimitedListener) Accept() (net.Conn, err) {
    <-l.sem // acquire
    // l.Listener.Accept (on error, release before returning)
    // wrap LimitedConn
    return c, nil
}

type LimitedConn struct { /* ... */ }

func (c *LimitedConn) Close() error {
    /* ... */
    c.sem <- true // release
}
```

Essentially what this is doing is creating your own implementation of net.Listener that you can give to [Serve](http://godoc.org/net/http#Server.Serve) that only calls the underlying Accept when it can acquire the semaphore; the semaphore so acquired is only released when the (suitably wrapped) [net.Conn](http://godoc.org/net#Conn) is Closed.  Note that technically this use of the semaphore is correct with respect to the go1.2 [memory model](http://golang.org/ref/mem); a simpler semaphore will be legal in [future versions](http://tip.golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_6) of Go.

Comment: Thank for Your reply. could you tell me
how to monitor the server (view number of active idle connections)???

Comment: store the original count, and subtract len(l.sem) from that to get (instantaneously) how many connections are waiting to be closed.

Comment: This might not be safe. I've occasionally seen multiple calls to Close() on the same Connection from net/http/Server. This is undefined behavior according to the io.Closer interface and with this implementation it results in Close() calls blocking when trying to release (read from chan). Consider using netutil.LimitListener as described in another answer instead; it has a wrapper to ensure that the channel is only read from once per connection. (It still passes the repeated Close calls to the underlying Listener though, which is still undefined behavior.)

Answer (score -1):

With the help of channel you can limit the count of active connections.

**1.At the server start up time create a channel and put equal number of limit count(in your case 20) values into the channel.**

**2.Remove one value from the channel while serving one request.**

One example from the web

```
type limitHandler struct {
    connc   chan struct{}
    handler http.Handler
}

func (h *limitHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    select {
    case <-connc:
        h.handler.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        connc <- struct{}{}
    default:
        http.Error(w, "503 too busy", StatusServiceUnavailable)
    }
}

func NewLimitHandler(maxConns int, handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    h := &limitHandler{
        connc:   make(chan struct{}, maxConns),
        handler: handler,
    }
    for i := 0; i < maxConns; i++ {
        connc <- struct{}{}
    }
    return h
}
```

Comment: `connc <- struct{}{}` should probably be `defer`-ed. Then, in case of a panic (that's recovered from elsewhere), the connection "slot" would still get returned to the pool.

Comment: Technically this doesn't limit incoming connections, it only limits how many responses you send at a time.  It is a useful pattern, though probably based on e.g. load rather than an absolute connection count.